# Admin List Dynamic Heading

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, admin

I want to modify dynamically the Heading1 that appears on top of the Admin List of posts. E.g. the Page heading of the Pages list.
[image: pages admin list]

I have exhausted all possible searches I could think of and nothing relevant came out.

Is there any function, filter, etc that allows us to modify what the content of the H1 heading of a custom post type list page would be?

I actually want to be able to add the title of a taxonomy when the list is filtered by that taxonomy.

Comment: There is no dedicated filter for this. See `wp-admin\edit.php`. WP uses `$post_type_object->labels->name` to output the text, so modifying that is likely going to require some kind of hacky approach since the the label text is used in other places as well.

Comment: I see:( -but thanks anyway @DaveRomsey - My fallback thought is to do some js...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you take a look at `wp-admin/edit.php`, you'll see that this string is printed with this line:

```
echo esc_html( $post_type_object->labels->name );
```

So there is no filter to modify it in `edit.php`.

There are no filters in `get_post_type_object` also, so we can't change it in there too, but...

The object for given post type is stored in global variable called `$wp_post_types`, so you can modify it:

```
function change_page_post_type_object() {
    global $wp_post_types;

    $wp_post_types['page']->labels->name = 'Not-Pages ;)';
}
add_action( 'init', 'change_page_post_type_object' );
```

And that's the result:

[image]

Comment: The issue I had with this is that it stomps on the name label indiscriminately. At a glance, I only see it modifying the `<title>` element of `edit.php`, which may actually be desirable in this case. Conditional statements should be added to this solution to minimize any possible fallout (ensure we're on `edit.php`, page is the post type, taxonomy is being filtered, etc) because it's reasonable to expect that plugins will make use of post type labels.

Comment: Yes, of course you’re right. The problem is that I don’t know what exactly should be changed and what is the reason for that change. If I’d change the title of posts list, then most of the times I’d like to also change that CPT name in other places... But that’s just guessing...